# Created raster is not following mouse

Tags: javascript, canvas

Icon moves when I move the mouse, but it doesn't move to the last position when I stop moving.

I used Paper.js for this.

My code:

```
    function setMousePosition(data) {
      var yyy;
      var deltaX;

      for (var i = 0; i < playersData.length; i++) {

        var element = playersData[i];

        if (element.playerName == data.playerName) {

         // element.cursor.position = new Point(data.position[1], data.position[2]);

          deltaX = (data.position[1] - element.cursor.position.x) / (100);
          yyy = (data .position[2] - element.cursor.position.y) / (100);

         var lastx =  element.cursor.position.x + deltaX;
         var lasty =  element.cursor.position.y + yyy;




          element.cursor.position = new Point(lastx,lasty);

        }

      }

    }
```

Icon doesn't move to cursor end position.

Comment: please check the value for your variable playersData. I think its not set in this function so the length is 0 and your code is not called.

Comment: socket.on('setMousePosition', function (data) {

  setMousePosition(data);


}) 

Sorry ı'm new user I forget share call function :) thanks for answers

Comment: okay your parameter is called "data" and in your function you use the variable "playerData" -> where is the variable "playerData" initialized?

Comment: you'll want to declare `lastx` and `lasty` outside of your `for...` loop, I think.

Comment: @JoshE i see no need for that...

Comment: I thought, but I can't make it move slowly because the loop completes fast.

Comment: İf you Want I'm sending project from mail 
 pls help because my term paper

Comment: I made this part by looking at the codes here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292350/make-ball-follow-mouse-on-canvas